# Why $k[X]/\langle f\rangle$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I am studying extensions of fields. $k[X]$ is a ring of polynomials (with coefficients in $k$) and $\langle f\rangle$ is an ideal generated by $f$, where $f$ is irreducible of degree $n\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$k[X]$ is a PID so if $f \in  k[X]$ is irreducible, then $(f)$ is a maximal ideal. Since we have

> $R/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal

then $k[X]/(f)$ is a field.

Comment: If f not are irreductible this will be ideal? maximal?

Comment: By definition, $\langle f`\rangle$ is the  (principal) ideal generated by $f$ (i.e. the set of multiples of $f$). This ideal is maximal if and only if $f$ is an irreducible polynomial.